# How can we create a XMLWriter in android?

Tags: android

How can we create a XMLWriter?The writer when passed to the parser will write the XML to the specified outputStream. Is there any direct class in android to acheive this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [XmlSerializer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html) to achieve your goal.
You can get some idea for creating XML [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#list11).

**Example**

```
private String writeXml(List<Message> messages){
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", "messages");
        serializer.attribute("", "number", String.valueOf(messages.size()));
        for (Message msg: messages){
            serializer.startTag("", "message");
            serializer.attribute("", "date", msg.getDate());
            serializer.startTag("", "title");
            serializer.text(msg.getTitle());
            serializer.endTag("", "title");
            serializer.startTag("", "url");
            serializer.text(msg.getLink().toExternalForm());
            serializer.endTag("", "url");
            serializer.startTag("", "body");
            serializer.text(msg.getDescription());
            serializer.endTag("", "body");
            serializer.endTag("", "message");
        }
        serializer.endTag("", "messages");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
}
```